# What TypeScript identifiers and constructs (apart from enums) 'survive' the compilation and can be accessed in JavaScript at runtime?

Tags: javascript, typescript

TypeScript compiles to JavaScript stripping nearly all of the TypeScript syntax and identifiers from the resulting JavaScript code. If given piece of TypeScript syntax is not a valid JavaScript code then you won't see a trace of it in the compiled output.

One exception that I know of is `enum`.

TypeScript code (invalid in JS)

```
enum Alph {
    a, b, c = "www"
}
```

actually shows in compiled JavaScript output as

```
var Alph;
(function (Alph) {
    Alph[Alph["a"] = 0] = "a";
    Alph[Alph["b"] = 1] = "b";
    Alph["c"] = "www";
})(Alph || (Alph = {}));
```

### Question

What TypeScript syntax constructs, other than `enum`, that are not JS constructs, compile to some JavaScript code and not just disappear? I'm especially interested in constructs that expose TypeScript identifiers in JS, like `enum` does.

### Clarification

Here's an example of what I have in mind when I say about TypeScript specific constructs and identifiers 'disappearing' from the output.

TypeScript

```
interface Inter {
    a: number;
}

class C implements Inter {
    a: number = 1;
}

var b: number = 1;
```

JavaScript compiler output

```
class C {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 1;
    }
}

var b = 1;
```

You can see that there's no trace of `interface`, `implement`, `Inter` or `number`. But the variable declaration and assignment is unchanged and `class` is passed to JS barely changed.

Default value was moved to the constructor so properties default values might be a minor example of what I'm looking for. Constructs that can't be just copied or removed but have to undergo some transformation to make sense in JS.

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean by "disappear".  What is an example of something specific that you'd like to be able to do?

Comment: @Pointy I added clarification.

Comment: Well once the TypeScript is compiled (or transpiled, if you like) to JavaScript, it really is just JavaScript. JavaScript doesn't have a concept of `interface` or typed variables, so there's nowhere for those concepts to be represented. So unless there are facilities *in TypeScript* to do things like type introspection, you don't get that in the JavaScript result.

Comment: @Pointy I'm aware of that, however JavaScript also doesn't have a concept of `enum` and yet there's a way for this concept to be represented in JavaScript. I'm looking for other mechanism in TypeScript that work like `enum`s. They exist in TypeScript, JavaScript has no concept of them and yet TypeScript compiler in some way introduces them into output JavaScript code.

Comment: ?? That's true of *every* TypeScript construct. It's translated into plain ordinary JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy You don't see any difference between how `interface` is translated to JS and how `enum` is translated to JS? How `interface` is gone because there's no concept of interface in JS and how `enum` is NOT gone and actually implemented in specific way using JS constructs even though there's no concept of `enum` in JS?

Comment: @Pointy To rephrase, if you remove `interface` declaration and usage manually, you'll end up with JS program that's still works exactly the same as typescript program you removed the `interface` from. You can't remove `enum` declaration and usage same way because the resulting JS program will no longer work. What are other constructs in TS that are not valid in JS but you can't just safely manually remove then because you'll break the program?

Comment: I guess I just don't understand what you're trying to actually *do*.  The `interface` declaration provides for *compile-time* static type checking. There's no need for it to become anything in the resulting JavaScript code once that type checking is complete at the end of compilation. The `enum` on the other hand has to be transformed into something at runtime.

Comment: @Pointy My question is: "What are TS constructs other than `enum` that have to be transformed into something at runtime?" and by TS constructs I mean constructs that are specific to TS. Constructs that that you have to TRANSFORM somehow to make them work in JS (not just copy like you do with classes, functions and all the usual JS code or just remove like interfaces or type declarations).

Comment: Basically all type declarations will vanish, but all concrete values will be kept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"What are TS constructs other than enum that have to be transformed into something at runtime?"*

The short answer is all of them, it's just a matter of how much. Keep in mind that Typescript is both a type system *and* a compiler. You code is being reconstructed into an abstract source tree, then re-emitted according the the logic of the compiler. So everything is always getting transformed, it's just that most of the time the output and the original code are pretty similar.

---

So I'm going to answer a more defined question that I think you're asking:

> *What Typescript keywords do not exist in JS, yet emit JS code when compiled.*

There are a few things (like [private instance variables `#foo`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?experimentalDecorators=true&ssl=4&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7oGIBmB7X0AvNAIwBMAzKhtAC4CmEtAFAJSLQBO9tArpwDs6ACwCWEAHQ58AX1QygA), [decorators `@f()`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?experimentalDecorators=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=4&pc=2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFASkQbwLAChEGIQIDOcANgKYB05cA5igESpoBcilAbgIbkg8olACZM0AbjyFEAJ0pQQMpKEiwEiFFB4z68gDSIADjLiHKMqAE8A0pUscSUGTDD0DwyiQjPDUODI4ABRMzC0sAEU9vGF9-DBx8aUJiMDIqWgZmVg4IPipRCSlCAF88Utw8FWh4JEZ4ooIUtJo6RiY6jm4+ASECyUSCOQUlZHBq9U1tXSgDY1NzK1t7REdnV3conz8AxGD5sMivLbisBqSmihbM9vQcvJExfuly8rwIch4SEkQAYVOBxAAAVYZ0BdTOAFt5AALODCdBYF5AA), or [JSX](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?experimentalDecorators=true&jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wFgAoCzAVwDsNgJa4AxCCACgEo4BvCuILhEY1KMwA8ACwCMAPgASSADbKIAGjgB1aMoAmEgPSy5FAL5A)). These are items that are in proposal stages of JS but not yet widely adopted, or are defined by other standards or transpilers, that have become first class citizen within the language of typescript. For those cases typescript outputs an equivalent implementation that should work in all modern JS interpreters that generates a lot of code the programmer isn't meant to utilize directly.

But I'm assuming you don't care about those cases too much either since the generated code could be removed if all interpreters supported these constructs the same way.

---

So that leaves:

- [`enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)
- [`namespace`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) (Though I think usage of `namespace` is discouraged for new typescript code these days, and the supporting code is pretty minimal)

And yeah. Pretty sure that's all of them.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! I'll accept it after I'll wait a bit if anyone else comes up with anything else juicy.